# I want to check if extracted word contains English letters

Tags: numbers, eval, extract, keyword, imacros

I'm having a big problem that I cant solve for days. I'm macro newbie and I want to compare Nb_1 i Nb_2 and Nb_3 and Nb_4.

My configuration is iMacros for FF v9.0.3 Firefox 50.1.0 Windows 10

Nb_1 and Nb_2 its numbers and that works.

Nb_3 and Nb_4 are words and there is a problem. I want to check if !EXTRACT word contains a','b','c','d','e','f','g'... and if yes {x=1;}   else{x=0;}

When I extract a word, if the word contains English letters and if yes - I want {x=1;}. If not I want {x=0;}.

This is my script

```
'Extract 1st Number:

SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=4 TYPE=TD ATTR=CLASS:text-center:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET Nb_1 {{!EXTRACT}}
'>
'Extract 2nd Number:

SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=5 TYPE=TD ATTR=CLASS:text-center:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET Nb_2 {{!EXTRACT}}
'>

 'Extract 3nd Word:
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=2 TYPE=H5 ATTR=CLASS:media-heading EXTRACT=TXT
SET Nb_3 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL

'Extract 4nd Word:
SET !EXTRACT NULL
SET Nb_4 {{'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',}}

TAG POS=R1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=CLASS:mainButton:* EXTRACT = HTM
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s = \"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s = s.split(' ')[1]; s=s.replace('id=', ''); s=s.replace('4045549725', '');s;")
SET Button EVAL("var n1='{{Nb_1}}', n2='{{Nb_2}}', n3='{{Nb_3}}', n4='{{Nb_4}}'; if((n1*1)>(n2*1)) else if(n3=n4) {x=1;}   else{x=0;} x;")

WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS={{Button}} TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:{{!VAR1}}
SET !VAR5 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*2 + 1); randomNumber;")
WAIT SECONDS={{!VAR5}}
```

Nb_1 and Nb_2 are working right, but when I try to check if word Nb_3 contains 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g... and so on, I get this error

expected expression, got keyword 'else', line: 30 (Error code: -1001)

This is working and comparing Nb_1 and Nb_2

```
SET Button EVAL("var n1='{{Nb_1}}', n2='{{Nb_2}}', n3='{{Nb_3}}', n4='{{Nb_4}}'; if((n1*1)>(n2*1)){x=1;} else{x=0;} x;")
```

But, when I add Nb_3 and Nb_4 I get and error. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? 
If someone has an idea how to solve this, please share.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And joining two conditions together:

```
SET Button EVAL("var x = 1; var w = '{{Nb_3}}'.replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase(); for (i = 0; i < w.length; i++) {if (w.charCodeAt(i) < 97 || w.charCodeAt(i) > 122) x = 0}; var n1='{{Nb_1}}', n2='{{Nb_2}}'; if((n1*1)>(n2*1)){y=1;} else{y=0;}; (x && y) ? 1 : 0;")
```

---

I think the following code should be helpful in your case:

```
SET Button EVAL("var x = 1; var w = '{{Nb_3}}'.replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase(); for (i = 0; i < w.length; i++) {if (w.charCodeAt(i) < 97 || w.charCodeAt(i) > 122) x = 0} x;")
```

---

At first you can try try this line:

```
SET Button EVAL("'{{Nb_3}}'.match(/\D/) ? 1 : 0;")
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @Shugar I tried but it's not working. This code compare Nb_1 and Nb_2 `SET Button EVAL("var n1='{{Nb_1}}', n2='{{Nb_2}}'; if((n1*1)>(n2*1)){x=1;} else{x=0;} x;") ` But when I add your code, it's not working. It doesn't recognize Arabic letters comparing to English letters.

Comment: This question is still unclear for me. Do you mean "at least one English letter" or "all English letters" in the `Nb_3` variable?

Comment: I mean all English leters if the word. I'll try to give you an example. If the word is (スポイト) that is x=0 and when is word (example) then is x=1. if the word is (examplポ) then is x=0. Important to me is that the word contains all English letters. Thanks again @Shugar

Comment: Thank you @Shugar. That code works. But I need them to work together. Do you know how to connect these two lines? Thanks again, you are amazing ! <br/> `SET Button EVAL("var x = 1; var w = '{{Nb_3}}'.replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase(); for (i = 0; i < w.length; i++) {if (w.charCodeAt(i) < 97 || w.charCodeAt(i) > 122) x = 0} x;")`
<br/>
`SET Button EVAL("var n1='{{Nb_1}}', n2='{{Nb_2}}'; if((n1*1)>(n2*1)){x=1;} else{x=0;} x;")`

Comment: Thank you @Shugar. You are a genius. This code works perfectly. All the best. Thanks again